# How to get the utf-8 character  equivalent to a Github emoji automatically?

Tags: emoji

I would like to know the utf-8 equivalent of `:heart:` ♥ or `:space_invader:` .

How to get the utf-8 character equivalent to a Github emoji automatically?

```
:heart: -> U+2764
:space_invader: -> U+1F47E
```

Comment: These names are likely to be specific to Github, so you'd need to look for a lookup table somewhere in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, package `unicodedata` works:

```
$ import unicodedata
$ alien=unicodedata.lookup(':alien monster:'.replace(':',''))

$ hex(ord(alien)).upper().replace('0X','U+')
'U+1F47E'
```

Not all Github emoji names work though.

Answer (score 0):

Github's package `gemoji` does so https://github.com/github/gemoji:

```
emoji = Emoji.find_by_alias "musical_note"
```